# How to retrieve the job list in AS400 using c#

Tags: ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

Recently, I need have to access the AS400 for monitor the night batch jobs and create the daily report which show all jobs and detail that ran.

In AS400 console, I can type "DSPMSG" command to get it.

In IBM System i Access for Windows, I can open the "System i Navigator" and get these information in Basic Operation - Messages.

But I am not sure how can I use C# to get these information.

Comment: If you have enough general familiarity, the [CWBSO_CreateListHandle API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/rzaik/rzaikcwbsocreatelisthandle.htm) used with a CWBSO_LISTTYPE type set for CWBSO_LIST_JOB might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other APIs, but the standard .NET dll only has the ability to interact with the database. Given that, you could write a RPG program and have a stored procedure call the RPG program and return the results.

Comment: Currently, I wrote the CL program in AS400 for insert to data into DB2. However, it is not a good solution. And I saw that there's other product called "EventLog Analyzer" can able to do that. Do you know any other APIs can do that?